# Remove the colon from line numbering in algpseudocode

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmic

Is there a way to remove the colon (:) from the line numbering in algorithms (using the `algpseudocode` package)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{Euclid}{a,b}
\State r\gets a\bmod b
\If{r\not=0}
\While{r\not=0} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State a\gets b  
\State b\gets r  
\State r\gets a\bmod b
\EndWhile
\EndIf 
\State \Return b \Comment{The g.c.d. is b} 
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

For example, instead of getting
[image]

we would get

[image]

Comment: Try `\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{}` before `\begin{algorithm}`. And Welcome to TeX.SX! Please working examples, not just a screen shot

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you for the quick reply. I've tried that but it didn't work. I added this before \begin{algorithmic}[1]

Comment: `didn't work` is not really useful. Please add the code, not the screenshots

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've edited the question - added the code for the first picture. The other one is from a book.

Comment: Was it really necessary to vote this down within less than an hour of the OP's first question? Sure, the question needs improvement but, you know, give that at least a few nanoseconds.

Comment: Could you expand your code snippet to a complete, compilable example? I.e. starting with `\documentclass`, containing all needed packages (but no more), and ending with `\end{document}`? Ideally it should be so that we can copy the code and compile it without making any changes, and see the same result as you show in the screenshot. I for one don't know all the algorithm packages that well, so figuring out which one(s) is required means trial and error.

Comment: My proposition was for `algorithm2e` package, but apparently the `algorithmic` environment is used, which comes from a different package, as far as I know

Comment: @TorbjørnT I'm sorry for this. I've edited the code so it could be compiled right away. What I did was simply copy paste from LyX, as it adds a lot of non relevant code by itself.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I now realize that I didn't even need this package. All I needed is algpseudocode package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to redefine `\alglinenumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\footnotesize #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\If{$r\not=0$}
\While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile
\EndIf
\State \Return $b$ \Comment{The g.c.d. is $b$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to number each line as "<number><period>" without using the algpseudocode package. I currently have algorithm and algorithmic package in my preamble and adding algpseudocode package is raising errors.

Comment: I think that with `algorithmic` you can do `\renewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\footnotesize #1.}` No need to load `algpseudocode`.

Comment: It raises an error -- \alglinenumber undefined.

Comment: @User525412790 Please make a fresh question with an example of algorithm with numbered lines using `algorithmic`.

Comment: I just did. The title of my question is `Changing line numbering format using algorithmic package`

Comment: Useful answer. I'd just suggest to add a little horizontal space after the line number: `\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize #1\enspace}`. [Sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xD15.png).